# How can I get more than 100 bucket objects? How can I list all the bucket objects?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge, autodesk-data-management

using https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-GET/ , I can set the limit as 100 and withdraw bucket objects. But how can I get all the bucket objects in a bucket key?

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/mybucketkey/objects?limit=100");
        request.Method = "Get";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.ContentType = "appication/json";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer my token" );


        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string myResponse = "";
        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            myResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I can list 100 in this way. But I couldn't find how to list them all. Could it be related to the startAt parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the reply contains a "**next**" property then you have to use that to get the next 100 items. Keep doing that until you get all items.
Yes, the **startAt** parameter will specify the next 100 you want to get back

See e.g. https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-buckets-tools/blob/master/server/data.management.js#L247

Comment: I sent requests to all of them (.next) one by one and kept them in a generic list.